# Need to execute "ps -ef | grep amq | awk '{print $(NF-1)}' " command in C++

Tags: c++, awk, ps

I am writing a c++ code in my project that should tell whether my websphere mq server is running or not. In order to extract that we need to run "/opt/mqm/bin/amq status" to show whether it is running or not.Tricky thing is MQHOME=/opt/mqm is not constant across unix platforms.So,We agreed to a design to extract the MQHOME path from the absolute path of the process "amqzlaar0" which is an mq server process.So, we need to issue the below command that shows the process "amqzlaar0" along with its fullpath.Then,we will store the string in an array to extract MQHOME.

```
"ps -ef | grep amqzlaar0 | awk '{print $(NF-1)}' "
```

system() function is failing with exit code -1 when i use pipe symbol "|". But, if I issue just system("ps -ef"),it works.

Please help me on how to execute a pipe seperated command using system.

Your help is much appreciated.
Regards,
Sriram

Comment: Piping functionality is provided by a shell, so it's not part of any single system command. I have very little experience with piping in C/C++ code but when I did it I manually set up pipes (file descriptors) for the communication.

Comment: Write a helper script containing your bash commands and then just run the helper script via system() or popen().

Comment: What system?  Posix requires `system` to pass the command through a shell, so the pipes _should_ work (and I've used similar commands from time to time with no problems).

Comment: You can shorten the `ps` some to: `ps -ef | awk '/[a]mqzlaar0/ {print $(NF-1)}'` Putting the `a` in brackets makes you not get the grep itself.

Comment: As Jotne points out, there's never a need to pipe the output of grep to awk, but in this case awk is unnecessary since you can control what ps outputs.  Try `ps -e -o command`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should not run a command to check that `amqzlaar0` is running, but query the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem (on Linux).

<sup>Notice that `/proc/` is not portable (e.g. not standardized in Posix). Some Unixes don't have it, and Solaris and Linux have very different `/proc/` file systems.</sup>

If really want to run a command, use e.g. [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to build the command (or `std::string` or `std::ostringstream`) then use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (and `pclose`) to run the command

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to get a better view of Linux Programming. See also [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

BTW, some people might have aliased e.g. `grep` (perhaps in their `.bashrc`), so you probably should put full paths in your command (so `/bin/grep` not `grep`  etc...).

Comment: He said Unix, not Linux.  The `proc` file system is nice, but it isn't portable.

Comment: Given that the question is about C++, why would you even suggest `snprintf`?  What he probably needs to use (if he's building a string) is `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `ps -Ef`. You're a C++ programmer.  The equivalent of `grep` and `awk` is not hard in C++, and it's faster in C++ (doesn't require two additional processes)

Comment: Thanks experts. I got it running using single ps process with out awk and grep.

Comment: on Linux it is :  ps -f -C amqzlaar0

Comment: On Solaris and AIX  it is: ps -f oargs= 
On HPUX it is: export UNIX95= ; ps -f -C amqzlaar0